# Development environment on an other website

Tags: web, development-environment, git-push

I have a website : `exemple.com`, and a clone of this website : `exemple.xyz`.

I want to know how to easily work on my clone *and* "push" my working code on my website.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your `example.com` server environment.

If you have access to that server, then you can add a bare repo, with a post-receive hook which would, after receiving a `git push`, restore files in your actual website folder. I describe that in "[How to Git Push to a Server Machine without having to ssh on to that machine every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246767/6309)".

That means you can push both to your fork and that destination server bare repo at the same time, as [explained here](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242):

```sh
git remote set-url --add --push origin /url1/fork.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin /url2/bare/repo.git
```

But if you don't, then it is best to use a third-party website manager [like Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/29/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-on-netlify/) to link your repository to said managed website: then a simple push would be enough to trigger a publication update.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will do the trick!